# How to show html in angularjs template instead of string?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable in my scope:

```
$scope.myvar = "Hello<br><br>World"
```

In my template I use:

```
<div>{{myvar}}</div>
```

The issue is myvar shows the literal text, whereas I want it to show the line breaks. How to do this? Note that I want to make it such that if I in the future, myvar gets updated with other HTML, then what is shown on the page should be the "compiled" html as opposed to the literal string with the html tags in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)** for that.
Keep in mind that due to Angular's **[Strict Conceptual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#Example)** the content needs to be either sanitized (using the additonal module `ngSanitize`) or explicitely "trustedAsHtml" (using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`). The latter is supposed to be used only for content you **know** is safe (e.g. nothing user defined) and is not recommended anyway.

<sub>**Note:** `ngSanitize` is an non-core module and should be included separately:

    `<script src=".../angular.min.js"></script>`

    `<script src=".../angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>`</sub>

Examples:

```
/* Using ngSanitize */
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myHtml = 'Hello<br /><br />world !';
});

/* Using $sce.trustAsHtml() */
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($sce, $scope) {
    $scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('Hello<br /><br />world !');
});
```

<sub>Note that `ngSanitize` will filter "non-appropriate" content, while `$sce.trustAsHtml` will allow anything.</sub>

See, also, this **[short demo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-bind-html` within `<div>`. Here is the example:

In your `html` file :

```
<div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="myvar"></div>
</div>
```

In your `js`:

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize']) 

.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.myvar = 'Hello<br><br>World';
                 }]);
```

Example taken from [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) doc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind-html` to bind to HTML directly. [Here's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

@ExpertSystem is correct or if you're lazy like me you could do:

```
lrApp.directive('bindHtml', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.bindHtml,function(nv,ov){
            elem.html(nv);
        });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the angular-sanitize.js library. This functionality used to be a part of the main library, but the Angular team has been splitting off sections to make it more modular.

2) Use the ng-bind-html tag:

```
<p ng-bind-html="myvar">
```