# Angular 2: How do you render HTML from a JSON response without displaying the tags to the user?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

**Edit:** a clarification for anyone who only skimmed the title, my question is about **Angular 2**, not 1.

---

I have a component template that is something like this:

```
<div>{{ post.body }}</div>
```

The object is something like:

```
{
    "title": "Some Title",
    "body": "<p>The <em>post body</em>.</p>"
}
```

Instead of rendering the paragraph like:

The *post body*

it displays:

`"<p>The <em>post body</em>.</p>"`

Since it's such a common task, I looked for a built-in pipe like `{{ post.body | safe }}` but didn't see one.

Is there is an easy way to get that working? Is there a safe way to get that working?

Comment: What are you using to add the json into your page?

Comment: please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826758/angularjs-render-html-tags-that-are-contained-in-a-string
and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747474/how-to-show-html-in-angularjs-template-instead-of-string

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436579/how-to-have-angularjs-output-escaped-html, or http://www.google.com

Comment: `<div [innerHTML]="post.body"></div>` for Angular2...

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - the JSON is from a service that obtains it from mock data at the moment, similar to how it's done on the angular.io tutorials.

Comment: That one is a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

In Angular2 you can use [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) to access properties of DOM elements, in your case:

```
<div [innerHTML]="post.body"></div>
```

Comment: But you should not do that https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xss

Comment: @CSchulz then what should be the secure way of doing it

Comment: You should only do it if you are sure that the source is trusted.

Comment: I want to append stuff to my html and not replace the innerHtml. Didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: If you bind to html with `[innerHTML]="yourHtml"` in Angular 4 it will sanitize the string and remove any <script> tags: https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts

Comment: how to use other tags, like <p> inside the div?

Comment: @CascadiaJS Thanks for the security link. Does that mean that the `safeHtml` pipe in the other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/4275029) is not needed?

Comment: @ibgib yup you don't need it anymore, Angular now sanitizes html content by default: https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts

Comment: If you need to use buttons or scripts, then pass the html through DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml (care, html must be from trusted source)

Comment: How to render **<a routerLink='home>Click</a>**