# Angular2, evaluate template from string inside a component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

It's possible evaluate template from string in a variable?. I need place the string in the component instead of the expression,
 e.g.

`template: "<div>{{ template_string }}</div>"`

*template_string* contains: `<b>{{ name }}</b>`

and all should be evaluated to `<div><b>My Name</b></div>`

but I see `<div>{{ template_string }}</div>`

I need something like `{{ template_string | eval }}` or something else to evaluate the content of the variable on current context.

It's possible? I need something to use this approach because `template_string` can be changed when the component is used.

> Edit1:

Angular Version: 4.0.3

E.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-item',
  template: `
    <div class="product">{{ template }}</div>`,
})
export class ProductItemComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() price: number = 0;
  @Input() template: string = `{{ name }} <b>{{ price | currency }}</b>`;
}
```

Usage:

```
<product-item [name]="product.name" [price]="product.price"></product-item>
```

**Expected:**    Product Name **USD3.00**

**Output:**     `{{ name }} <b>{{ price | currency }}</b>`

Comment: You may look at [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)

Comment: does not work, tested with `4.0.3`, output the string as is: `<div>{{ template_string }}</div>`

Comment: Are you using AOT?

Comment: not, suppose JIT, I'm currently running whit `npm start`. I'm a beginner, this is my first project using angular2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create your own directive that will do it:

**compile.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[compile]'
})
export class CompileDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() compile: string;
  @Input() compileContext: any;

  compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(!this.compile) {
      if(this.compRef) {
        this.updateProperties();
        return;
      }
      throw Error('You forgot to provide template');
    }

    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.compRef = null;

    const component = this.createDynamicComponent(this.compile);
    const module = this.createDynamicModule(component);
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
      .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        let compFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === component);

        this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
        this.updateProperties();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  updateProperties() {
    for(var prop in this.compileContext) {
      this.compRef.instance[prop] = this.compileContext[prop];
    }
  }

  private createDynamicComponent (template:string) {
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-dynamic-component',
      template: template,
    })
    class CustomDynamicComponent {}
    return CustomDynamicComponent;
  }

  private createDynamicModule (component: Type<any>) {
    @NgModule({
      // You might need other modules, providers, etc...
      // Note that whatever components you want to be able
      // to render dynamically must be known to this module
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [component]
    })
    class DynamicModule {}
    return DynamicModule;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-item',
  template: `
    <div class="product">
      <ng-container *compile="template; context: this"></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ProductItemComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() price: number = 0;
  @Input() template: string = `{{ name }} <b>{{ price | currency }}</b>`;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTg0Zplq85WpEPC50jyH?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular 2.1.0 create child component on the fly, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks!! again ;)

Comment: This solution seems to break if the compile directive is used more than once? Any components I declare in the declarations of the dynamic module will be loaded in two modules with the same name, and the compilation crashes.

Comment: @zxz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678963/load-existing-components-dynamically-angular-2-final-release/39680765#39680765

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you're building the template string

```
import { ..., OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-item',
    template: `
    <div class="product" [innerHtml]='template_string'>
    </div>`,
    })
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() price: number = 0;
    @Input() pre: string;
    @Input() mid: string;
    @Input() post: string;
    template_string;
    ngOnInit() {
        // this is probably what you want
        this.template_string = `${this.pre}${this.name}${this.mid}${this.price}${this.post}`
    }
}

<product-item [name]="name" [price]="price" pre="<em>" mid="</em><b>" post="</b>"></product-item>
```

the string can be built from outside the component, would still recommend something like ngIf to control dynamic templates though.

Comment: it's not my use case, I really need evaluate from string, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44073940/4724040, it's a similar unresolved use case

Answer (score 0):

In Angular double curly braces `{{}}` are used to evaluation an expression in a component's template. and not work on random strings or dynamically added DOM elements. So one way of doing this is to use typescript string interpolation using `${}`. check the rest of code to understand

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-item',
  template: `
    <div class="product" [innerHTML]="template"></div>`,
})
export class ProductItemComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() price: number = 0;
  @Input() template: string = `${ this.name } <b>${ this.price }}</b>`;
}
```