# Mixing ES6 Template Literals with Angular Expressions

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have the following bit of text as a value in a `key - value` pair:

```
`${site.name} was added successfully.<br>
The URL for this site is
<a href="{{ 'domain' | i18n: {url: domain} }}" target="_blank">
{{ 'domain' | i18n: {url: domain} }}</a>.`,
```

It seems like because I am mixing template literals and and Angular expressions, I am unable to get the expression to print out the value, and it instead just prints: `{{ 'domain' | i18n: {url: domain} }}`

Any ideas on how to combine both?

Thanks

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @MisterMystery 4

Comment: Ahh I haven't used 4 much so can't really help. My first thought was to use `$interpolate` in Angular 1 but I think that has been removed in Angular 2+. Maybe this [post will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077994/angular2-evaluate-template-from-string-inside-a-component).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
[
  `${site.name} was added successfully.<br>`,
  `The URL for this site is`,
  `<a href="`,
  "{{ 'domain' | i18n: {url: domain} }}",
  '" target="_blank">',
  "{{ 'domain' | i18n: {url: domain} }}</a>"`
].join('');
```