# Angular: bind variables inside [innerHtml]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to bind data inside a div using [innerHtml]. How to notify angular to use the variables instead of the raw text. Here is my setup :

```
<div *ngFor="let data of someData">
    <div *ngFor="let odata of someOtherData;trackBy:id">
        <div [innerHTML]="odata.template | pipeToSanitize"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data looks like this :

```
someOtherData = [{
                    'id': 1,
                    'template': '<div class="{{data.class}}"><md-icon>{{data.icon}}</md-icon></div>'
                }, 
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'template': '<div>{{data.timestampStr}}</div>'
                }, 
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'template': '<div>{{data.message}}</div>'
                }]

someData = [{
               'message': 'Message 1',
               'timestampStr': '2016/12/13 09:25:00',
               'class': 'events-warn-color',
               'icon': 'warning'
            }, 
           {
               'message': 'Message 2',
               'timestampStr': '2016/12/13 10:36:00',
               'class': 'events-warn-color',
               'icon': 'warning'
           }];
```

Now I am getting {{data.icon}},etc. as it is. How can replace this with the contents from 'someOtherData' object. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create compiler directive to evaluate the template string:

**compile.directive.ts**

```
  @Directive({
    selector: '[compile]'
  })
  export class CompileDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input() compile: string;
    @Input() compileContext: any;

    compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
      if(!this.compile) {
        if(this.compRef) {
          this.updateProperties();
          return;
        }
        throw Error('You forgot to provide template');
      }

      this.vcRef.clear();
      this.compRef = null;

      const component = this.createDynamicComponent(this.compile);
      const module = this.createDynamicModule(component);
      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
        .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
          let compFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === component);

          this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
          this.updateProperties();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    updateProperties() {
      for(var prop in this.compileContext) {
        this.compRef.instance[prop] = this.compileContext[prop];
      }
    }

    private createDynamicComponent (template:string) {
      @Component({
        selector: 'custom-dynamic-component',
        template: template,
      })
      class CustomDynamicComponent {}
      return CustomDynamicComponent;
    }

    private createDynamicModule (component: Type<any>) {
      @NgModule({
        // You might need other modules, providers, etc...
        // Note that whatever components you want to be able
        // to render dynamically must be known to this module
        imports: [CommonModule],
        declarations: [component]
      })
      class DynamicModule {}
      return DynamicModule;
    }
  }
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of someData">
    <div *ngFor="let odata of someOtherData;">
          <ng-container *compile="odata.template; context:{data:data}"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

> You still need to deal with angular material module , I haven't impliment that to my online example, just check compile direactive comment

[stackblitz template compile](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-compile)

Check this [Angular2, evaluate template from string inside a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077994/angular2-evaluate-template-from-string-inside-a-component)

Comment: Thanks bro. Works as expected. In AngularJS we could have done this with 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `[innerHTML]`?

Try

```
<div>{{odata.template | pipeToSanitize}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[innerHtml] is great option in most cases, but it fails with really large strings or when you need hard-coded styling in html.

you can check for answers in the following to get a good idea. Specially **Piotrek's** answer

[Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311)

Answer (score -1):

EDITED: can you try this too:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of someData">
    <div *ngFor="let odata of getData(data);trackBy:id">
        <div [innerHTML]="odata.template | pipeToSanitize"></div>
    </div>
</div>

getDataFormated(data:any):any{
return [{
                    'id': 1,
                    'template': '<div class="{{data.class}}"><md-icon>{{data.icon}}</md-icon></div>'
                }, 
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'template': '<div>{{data.timestampStr}}</div>'
                }, 
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'template': '<div>{{data.message}}</div>'
                }]
}
```

Comment: Already tried that bro. The tslint is throwing error saying data is not defined.

Comment: Try the new solution guy!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed the solution to use template literals and it works. But I will have to do extra 'dirty' work as the structure of 'someOtherData' can change.

Comment: There is md-icon component required runtime compile @DanielSeguraPérez