# Evaluate expression twice in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to evaluate an expression coming from the one component inside other component.

Below is the code

**Parent.component.ts**

```
parentData: any= {
    name: 'xyz',
    url: '/test?testid={{element["TestId"]}}'
};
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<child [data]="parentData"></child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({ 
selector:'child'
...
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() data: any;
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <a href="{{data.url}}">{{element["TestName"]}}</a>
</td>
```

The href is being evaluated as `/test?testid={{element["TestId"]}}`. What it needs to be is `/test?testid=123`

```
element["TestId"] - is to be evaluated in child scope.
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077994/angular2-evaluate-template-from-string-inside-a-component) but I am not sure how can I apply it in my case.

**EDIT:** 
Adding link for [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q68djy-3hs4sz) contains similar example. 
I'm trying to make my ChildComponent generic, that's why is want the parent to decide which column to evaluate for `element["TestId"]`
Please ignore my edits, I'm still learning on how to write the question better.

Comment: try this ` url: `/test?testid=${ExpressionToBeEvaluatedInChildScope}` `

Comment: @AbdulBasit I did try that already, it doesn't work.

Comment: then you should do this `url: '/test?testid='+ExpressionToBeEvaluatedInChildScope`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to put in `ExpressionToBeEvaluatedInChildScope `?

Comment: @ConnorsFan just updated my question

Comment: Can `element["TestId"]` change after some time?

Comment: @ConnorsFan exactly.

Comment: If you defined `urlPrefix` in `parentData` (without the id binding part), you could do this in the child component: `href="{{ data.urlPrefix + element['TestId'] }}"`. Or `[href]="data.urlPrefix + element['TestId']"`.

Comment: I'm trying to make the child component generic. So I want the parent to decide whether it should be a `TestId` or `TestCaseId` or some random column.

Comment: Added StackBlitz link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function from that property

```
parentGridData = {
  ...
  url: element => `http://www.google.com/searchText=${element["name"]}`
};
```

and then pass an appropriate argument to it:

```
<a href="{{gridData?.url(element)}}">
```

But make sure that your function doesn't contain heavy computations.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q68djy-fjkben?file=app/parent.ts)**