# how to dynamically load angular components according to their names in json file

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I'm looking for a way to load dynamically angular component.
The component name should be stored in a json file, and the service should load the component according to its name in the json file.
The second step should be storing the html of the rendered component into a div innerHTML.
I'm already doing it using a regular HTML page.

Comment: Seems like [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) might be what you're looking for.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-container-conditional?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: May be you can save selector of component and you can render it like the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/44082399/10377603