# what are the possible ways to bind a variable from its string equivalent in angular

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I need a way to bind a variable in a string.

for example in Ts:

name = '{{first}}';

and in HTML if I have :

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="first">
 <div> {{name}} <div>
```

This should return what ever is being typed in the input and not '{{first}}'
how can I achieve that ?

I Have a test code at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxpw57?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interpolation `{{ }}` in the controller. It is restricted to HTML templates.

What you could do is assign the member variable using `this` keyword.

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  name1 = this.name;
}
```

However this is a one-time assignment. Any changes to `name` variable using the `<input>` tag won't affect the `name1` variable.

Comment: Actually we are getting the interpolation string straight from Database and can not assign it in controller. I can understand that I m assigning the value as a string so its being resolved as a string, but I want a way it can be parsed as an expression.

Comment: @Nar: So for eg. if the database sends `{{ id }}`, do we assume there already is an existing member variable like `public id = 5`? If not, you cannot use the interpolation anyway. To use the interpolation, the value must exist in the controller.

Comment: Yes, we are using formly and both the fields and the model will be passed to UI from an API. So the {{ id }} will be in the model and variable id will be two way binded with one of the field in the UI. The model data will be in the controller.

Comment: If the backend sends both `id` and `{{ id }}`, then what exactly is the purpose of `{{ id }}`? You could ignore it and bind to the `id` variable directly.

Comment: The string that comes as interpolation from DB is more like {{ID}} + {{ID1}} more like an expression based on input from the user for one or more fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077994/angular2-evaluate-template-from-string-inside-a-component this post had the answer I needed. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your requirements but Angular already supports two way binding

[Updated stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwmkcr).

Comment: Yeah I want the two way binding to happen through a variable.