# Quill error: 'quill Invalid Quill container'

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I'm using angular 4 and a quill editor. but I get an error of `quill Invalid Quill container`. I change the name of the container but it still returns the error and cannot identify the container id. I create my quill object in ngOninit but it's not working! these are my codes:

```
import * as Quill from 'quill';
quill;
this.quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: { container: '#toolbar-toolbar' }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

and this is HTML file:

```
<md-card>
  <div class="toolbar border-none" id="toolbar-toolbar">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-size">
        <option value="small"></option>
        <option selected=""></option>
        <option value="large"></option>
        <option value="huge"></option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-strike"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-color"></select>
      <select class="ql-background"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
      <select class="ql-align">
        <option selected=""></option>
        <option value="center"></option>
        <option value="right"></option>
        <option value="justify"></option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-link"></button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <hr class="ma-0">
  <div class="border-none capital" id="editor-container" #content>
    <span class="font direct"></span>
  </div>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Try to use ngx-quill which is developed for angular https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko and do you know how can i save the styles like bold, italic and ... in database? i can use them in quill but when i save the text it's not bold  or italic anymore

Comment: In your html you should use ``<div [innerHtml]="response.text"></div>``, because so you can output the formated text content from API/DB. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936027/angular-2-how-do-you-render-html-from-a-json-response-without-displaying-the-ta

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately I am not an Angular expert but I had exactly the same issue with Vue.js.
The problem was that Quill was initiated before the DOM container element was properly rendered. If you can make it sure (use a later lifecycle hook or try to initiate the toolbar in the options, not in the markup), it should work.

Comment: This was it for me, kinda obvious when you think about it. Solved my issue for mentions in React by using useEffect (componentDidMount would work too)

Answer (score 4):

Quill was called before DOM container is rendered. You can delay constructing Quill by using setTimeOut

```
var editorId = "some-id-name"
setTimeout( () =>
{
    var container = document.getElementById(editorId);
    var editor    = new Quill( container );
}, 3000 );   
// 3000 millisec is maybe too long but too make sure that the problem is from creating 
// Quill before DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to some of the existing answers; using **ngAfterViewInit()** removed the need for a manual delay in my usecase.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: {
        container: '#toolbar-toolbar'
      }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There other people looking into this, in my case moving the logic to `ngOnInit` solved the problem. Or just check when trying to initialize quill to have the dom element rendered.