# How to Add an Html Snippet (that has the <script> tag and css code) into an Angular Component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, script-tag

**> Note that the Html snippet has the `<script>`tag in it and therefore the problem cannot be solved with Html binding**

I am trying to add an Html snippet (that I receive from an API response) to a component in angular.  The response looks something like this:

```json
{
  "abc": "1234",
  "html_snippet": "<div id=\"klarna-checkout-container\" style=\"overflow-x: hidden;\">\n  <div id=\"klarna-unsupported-page\">\n  <style type=\"text/css\">\n  @-webkit-keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}@-moz-keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}@keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}#klarna-unsupported-page{opacity:0;opacity:1\\9;-webkit-animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;-moz-animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards;-webkit-animation-duration:.1s;-moz-animation-duration:.1s;animation-duration:.1s;-webkit-animation-delay:5s;-moz-animation-delay:5s;animation-delay:5s;text-align:center;padding-top:64px}#klarna-unsupported-page .heading{font-family: \"Klarna Headline\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(23, 23, 23);font-size: 36px;letter-spacing: -0.2px;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}#klarna-unsupported-page .subheading{font-family: \"Klarna Text\", \"Klarna Sans\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(23, 23, 23);-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;line-height: 28px;font-weight: 400;font-size: 19px;max-width: 640px;margin: 20px auto;}#klarna-unsupported-page .reload {cursor: pointer;outline: none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);border-width: 1px;background-color: rgb(38, 37, 37);border-color: rgb(38, 37, 37);padding: 15px 24px;margin-top: 15px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-family: \"Klarna Text\", \"Klarna Sans\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;text-rendering: geometricprecision;min-width: 650px;font-size: 100%;}\n  </style>\n  <h1 class=\"heading\">Something went wrong</h1>\n  <p class=\"subheading\">Sorry for any inconvenience, please try reloading the checkout page or try again later.</p>\n  <p class=\"subheading\">If the problem persists it maybe be because you are using an old version of the web browser which is not safe nor compatible with modern web sites. For a smoother checkout experience, please install a newer browser.</p>\n  <button class=\"reload\" onclick=\"reloadCheckoutHandler && reloadCheckoutHandler()\">Reload checkout</button>\n  </div>\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  /* <![CDATA[ */\n  var reloadCheckoutHandler;\n  (function(w,k,i,d,n,c,l){\n    w[k]=w[k]||function(){(w[k].q=w[k].q||[]).push(arguments)};\n    l=w[k].config={\n      container:w.document.getElementById(i),\n      ORDER_URL:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/eu/kco/checkout/orders/21178ef0-b102-6367-8ed4-ec294da31abb',\n      AUTH_HEADER:'KlarnaCheckout avogscd619khph8erlcx',\n      LOCALE:'en-GB',\n      ORDER_STATUS:'checkout_incomplete',\n      MERCHANT_NAME:'Your business name',\n      GUI_OPTIONS:[],\n      ALLOW_SEPARATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:false,\n      PURCHASE_COUNTRY:'gbr',\n      PURCHASE_CURRENCY:'GBP',\n      TESTDRIVE:true,\n      BOOTSTRAP_SRC:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/kcoc/210325-ff251c7/checkout.bootstrap.js',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_URL:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/eu/kco/checkout/orders/21178ef0-b102-6367-8ed4-ec294da31abb/device_recognition',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE1:true,\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE3_ORG_ID:'87rxrdob',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE3_REF:'KLRNA_87rxrdob_21178ef0-b102-6367-8ed4-ec294da31abb',\n      CLIENT_EVENT_HOST:'https://eu.playground.klarnaevt.com'\n    };\n    n=d.createElement('script');\n    c=d.getElementById(i);\n    n.async=!0;\n    n.src=l.BOOTSTRAP_SRC;\n    c.appendChild(n);\n    try{\n      ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =\n        l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST + '/v1/checkout/snippet/load' +\n        '?sid=' + l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1) +\n        '&order_status=' + w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS) +\n        '&timestamp=' + (new Date).getTime();\n    }catch(e){}\n    reloadCheckoutHandler = function () {\n        try{\n            ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =\n            l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST+'/v1/checkout/snippet/reload?sid='+l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1)+\n            '&order_status='+w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS)+'&timestamp='+(new Date()).getTime();\n            window.location.reload();\n        }catch(e){}\n    }\n  })(this,'_klarnaCheckout','klarna-checkout-container',document);\n  /* ]]> */\n  </script>\n  <noscript>\nPlease <a href=\"http://enable-javascript.com\">enable JavaScript</a>.\n  </noscript>\n</div>",
  "def": "567"
}
```

If I place the value of the **HTML snippet** to the `textarea` section of the `index.html` file in the Angular project, I achieve the desired outcome.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>....</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <textarea style="display: none" id="KCO">
        <div id=\"klarna-checkout-container\" style=\"overflow-x: hidden;\">\n  <div id=\"klarna-unsupported-page\">\n  <style type=\"text/css\">\n  @-webkit-keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}@-moz-keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}@keyframes klarnaFadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}#klarna-unsupported-page{opacity:0;opacity:1\\9;-webkit-animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;-moz-animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;animation:klarnaFadeIn ease-in 1;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards;-webkit-animation-duration:.1s;-moz-animation-duration:.1s;animation-duration:.1s;-webkit-animation-delay:5s;-moz-animation-delay:5s;animation-delay:5s;text-align:center;padding-top:64px}#klarna-unsupported-page .heading{font-family: \"Klarna Headline\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(23, 23, 23);font-size: 36px;letter-spacing: -0.2px;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}#klarna-unsupported-page .subheading{font-family: \"Klarna Text\", \"Klarna Sans\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: rgb(23, 23, 23);-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;line-height: 28px;font-weight: 400;font-size: 19px;max-width: 640px;margin: 20px auto;}#klarna-unsupported-page .reload {cursor: pointer;outline: none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);border-width: 1px;background-color: rgb(38, 37, 37);border-color: rgb(38, 37, 37);padding: 15px 24px;margin-top: 15px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-family: \"Klarna Text\", \"Klarna Sans\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;text-rendering: geometricprecision;min-width: 650px;font-size: 100%;}\n  </style>\n  <h1 class=\"heading\">Something went wrong</h1>\n  <p class=\"subheading\">Sorry for any inconvenience, please try reloading the checkout page or try again later.</p>\n  <p class=\"subheading\">If the problem persists it maybe be because you are using an old version of the web browser which is not safe nor compatible with modern web sites. For a smoother checkout experience, please install a newer browser.</p>\n  <button class=\"reload\" onclick=\"reloadCheckoutHandler && reloadCheckoutHandler()\">Reload checkout</button>\n  </div>\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  /* <![CDATA[ */\n  var reloadCheckoutHandler;\n  (function(w,k,i,d,n,c,l){\n    w[k]=w[k]||function(){(w[k].q=w[k].q||[]).push(arguments)};\n    l=w[k].config={\n      container:w.document.getElementById(i),\n      ORDER_URL:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/eu/kco/checkout/orders/871abc62-f809-64a7-87e6-cf4c348ff9ca',\n      AUTH_HEADER:'KlarnaCheckout 0o07g27rew7kvpwx75il',\n      LOCALE:'en-GB',\n      ORDER_STATUS:'checkout_incomplete',\n      MERCHANT_NAME:'Your business name',\n      GUI_OPTIONS:[],\n      ALLOW_SEPARATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:false,\n      PURCHASE_COUNTRY:'gbr',\n      PURCHASE_CURRENCY:'GBP',\n      TESTDRIVE:true,\n      BOOTSTRAP_SRC:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/kcoc/210322-fe1ceb3/checkout.bootstrap.js',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_URL:'https://js.playground.klarna.com/eu/kco/checkout/orders/871abc62-f809-64a7-87e6-cf4c348ff9ca/device_recognition',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE1:true,\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE3_ORG_ID:'87rxrdob',\n      DEVICE_RECOGNITION_TYPE3_REF:'KLRNA_87rxrdob_871abc62-f809-64a7-87e6-cf4c348ff9ca',\n      CLIENT_EVENT_HOST:'https://eu.playground.klarnaevt.com'\n    };\n    n=d.createElement('script');\n    c=d.getElementById(i);\n    n.async=!0;\n    n.src=l.BOOTSTRAP_SRC;\n    c.appendChild(n);\n    try{\n      ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =\n        l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST + '/v1/checkout/snippet/load' +\n        '?sid=' + l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1) +\n        '&order_status=' + w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS) +\n        '&timestamp=' + (new Date).getTime();\n    }catch(e){}\n    reloadCheckoutHandler = function () {\n        try{\n            ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =\n            l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST+'/v1/checkout/snippet/reload?sid='+l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1)+\n            '&order_status='+w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS)+'&timestamp='+(new Date()).getTime();\n            window.location.reload();\n        }catch(e){}\n    }\n  })(this,'_klarnaCheckout','klarna-checkout-container',document);\n  /* ]]> */\n  </script>\n  <noscript>\nPlease <a href=\"http://enable-javascript.com\">enable JavaScript</a>.\n  </noscript>\n</div>
</textarea>

  <div id="my-checkout-container"></div>

  <!-- START - Dont edit -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var checkoutContainer = document.getElementById('my-checkout-container')
    checkoutContainer.innerHTML = (document.getElementById("KCO").value).replace(/\\"/g, "\"").replace(/\\n/g, "");
    var scriptsTags = checkoutContainer.getElementsByTagName('script')
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptsTags.length; i++) {
      var parentNode = scriptsTags[i].parentNode
      var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script')
      newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'
      newScriptTag.text = scriptsTags[i].text
      parentNode.removeChild(scriptsTags[i])
      parentNode.appendChild(newScriptTag)
    }
  </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

However, since the API response is dynamic and therefore will change on every request, I would like to insert the snippet in a component's Html file so that I create the div on **button click**.

This question is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936027/angular-2-how-do-you-render-html-from-a-json-response-without-displaying-the-ta) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) because there is javascript+css inside the snippet. I imagine that implementing the functionality of the scrript at the bottom of the `index.html` file into the  `xxxxxx.component.ts` file would be part of the solution.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkoutContainer = document.getElementById('my-checkout-container')
    checkoutContainer.innerHTML = (document.getElementById("KCO").value).replace(/\\"/g, "\"").replace(/\\n/g, "");
    var scriptsTags = checkoutContainer.getElementsByTagName('script')
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptsTags.length; i++) {
      var parentNode = scriptsTags[i].parentNode
      var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script')
      newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'
      newScriptTag.text = scriptsTags[i].text
      parentNode.removeChild(scriptsTags[i])
      parentNode.appendChild(newScriptTag)
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You are basically hacking yourself here. Script Injection is one of JavaScript's major vulnerabilities, and something an HTML 5 browser with a Content-Security-Policy won't let you do.

Comment: @ControlAltDel can the functionality of the scripts be implemented on a component's ```.ts``` file and as a result, avoid the Content-Security-Policy restrictions in HTML 5?

Comment: I am not using Typescript so I can't say for sure. But I think it's highly likely that it will work. The only scripts I believe that CSP watches out for are the inline ones on the page